# Separability of the expansion solution of the Klein-Gordon PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

I have the Klein-Gordon equation:
$$\big{(}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}}-\Delta+m^{2}\big
{)}\phi(t,x) = 0.$$
I am assuming $\phi = \phi(t,x)$ to be defined on $\mathbb{R}\times B$ where $B$ is a box $B = [-L,L]^{d} \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$. I know from my physics book that $\phi(t,x)$ can be expanded as follows:
$$\phi(t,x) = \sum_{p \in B^{*}}\alpha(t)e_{p}(x)$$
where $B^{*}$ is the momentum space associated with $B$ and for each momentum $p \in B^{*}$, $e_{p}(x)$ is an eigenvalue of the Laplacian $\Delta$.

I want to be able to justify the above formulas in a rigorous way. As far as I understand, the momentum space $B^{*}$ is a (countably infinite) lattice and the eigenvectors of the Laplacian are $e_{p}(x) = L^{-d/2}e^{i p \cdot x}$, with $p\cdot x$ being the inner product in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and I believe this is a basis for $L^{2}(B)$. However, why can I expand $\phi(t,x)$ as before? That is, (at each term of the sum) why can I separate the time entry and the position entry $\alpha(t)e_{p}(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the statement that a solution $\phi$, if it exists, admits this kind of decomposition is simply justified by the fact that, as you said, the eigenvectors $\left\{e_p(x)\right\}$ form a basis of $L^2(B)$: we do not even need that $\phi$ is a solution but just that $\phi(t,\cdot) \in L^2(B)$ for any $t \in \mathbb{R}$ (true if $\phi$ is a regular solution, or at least continuous).

However, in (mathematical) physics people are not interested in expanding solutions of PDEs using random bases, but in finding a basis which has a physical meaning. Indeed, the significant aspect is that each single term of the sum
$$\phi_p(t,x)=\alpha_p(t)e_p(x)$$
is itself a solution of the original PDE, and so we can expand a generic solution as a sum of "elementary" solutions. This approach allows us to construct by hand, in a very physical manner, a generic solution of the equation (starting from the elementary ones and using the *superposition principle*, which by the way requires some justifications for infinite sums) rather than relying on abstract existence theorems.

About the existence of *separable* elementary solutions of this form: as far as I know there are no results which provide it in general settings, but this is a strategy that works for many classical PDEs. One substitutes $\phi(t,x)=\alpha(t)\beta(x)$ in the equation in attempt to find this kind of solutions, which is convenient because one obtains two easier equations for $\alpha$ and $\beta$. If we are lucky, we will find a set of solutions $\left\{\alpha_i(t)\beta_i(x)\right\}_i$ with $\left\{\beta_i\right\}_i$ being a basis of $L^2$. In this particular case we have
$$\beta(x)\alpha''(t)-\alpha(t)\Delta\beta(x)+m^2\alpha(t)\beta(x)=0$$
which becomes
$$\frac{\alpha''(t)}{\alpha(t)}+m^2=\frac{\Delta\beta(x)}{\beta(x)}=C$$
and so $\beta(x)$ has to be an eigenvector of the Laplacian (with $C \in \mathbb{R}$ usually chosen s.t. $\phi$ satisfies some additional conditions, like boundary conditions).

Comment: @InMathweTrust so is this the kind of answer you were looking for? Is it ok?